# How do I know what option the user has selected from this LabelOptionBox function?

Tags: python, appjar

I have this OptionBox.   How do I actually know what option the user has chosen?

`app.addLabelOptionBox("Item", ["Choose an item from this list", "Apple", "Orange", "Pear", "kiwi", "- Pets -", "Dogs", "Cats", "Fish", "Hamsters"])`

Its from the AppJar library.  Is it simply to add a variable (and what type of variable?) at the front?
`thevalue = app.addLabelOptionBox(...`

There's not much documentation on this at all.
I don't know how to query this addLabelOptionBox to find out what value has been chosen.

Comment: http://appjar.info/inputWidgets/#optionbox

Comment: ok... it is `optionchosen = app.getOptionBox("title")` I was expecting to find a `.getLabelOptionBox()`  `optionchosen` being a string.